# Returning a LINQ database query from a Method

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Hello everyone I have this query I am performing in multiple places. Instead of retyping the query over and over, I would like to be able to call a method that returns the query. I am not sure what to put as the return type for the method or if this is even possible to do. I use the query to write a csv file of the information, and I use the query to add items to my observable collection that is bound to a list view.

```
using (ProjectTrackingDBEntities context = new ProjectTrackingDBEntities())
{
    var result = context.TimeEntries.Where(Entry => Entry.Date >= FilterProjectAfterDate
                                && Entry.Date <= FilterProjectBeforerDate
                                && (FilterProjectName != null ? Entry.ProjectName.Contains(FilterProjectName) : true))
        .GroupBy(m => new { m.ProjectName, m.Phase })
        .Join(context.Projects, m => new { m.Key.ProjectName, m.Key.Phase }, w => new { w.ProjectName, w.Phase }, (m, w) => new { te = m, proj = w })
        .Select(m => new
        {
            Name = m.te.Key.ProjectName,
            Phase = m.te.Key.Phase,
            TimeWorked = m.te.Sum(w => w.TimeWorked),
            ProposedCompletionDate = m.proj.ProposedCompletionDate,
            ActualCompletionDate = m.proj.ActualCompletionDate,
            Active = m.proj.Active,
            StartDate = m.proj.StartDate,
            Description = m.proj.Description,
            EstimatedHours = m.proj.EstimatedHours
        });
}
```

I am able to do both right now by retyping the query and performing the subsequent `foreach()` loops on the data. I would rather be able to do something like:

```
var ReturnedQuery = GetProjectsQuery();
foreach(var item in ReturnedQuery)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your return type right now is an enumerable of an anonymous type. You could make a class to represent that anonymous type and return `IEnumerable<YourType>` for your wuery.

Comment: Sounds like you want an IQueryable<T> for a return type...

Comment: Microsoft docs [return-a-query-from-a-method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/return-a-query-from-a-method)

Comment: @JaredStroeb I don't think that's correct as its about Object-to-LINQ, not Database-to-LINQ. His method would need to return IQueryable instead of IEnumerable.

Comment: @ckuri Looks like both will work IEnumerable is inherited by IQueryable, Hence IQueryable has all the features of IEnumerable and it has its own features. [ienumerable vs iqueryable](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/linq/ienumerable-vs-iqueryable)

Comment: @JaredStroeb You are right, but I don't think you can extend the query with a further Where or Select statement. The signature for Where is Queryable.Where(IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) vs Enumerable.Where(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate). Queryables build an expression tree, which can be parsed and converted to an SQL statement. This isn't possible for Enumerables, thus I would assume when you return an IEnumerable and try to add an Where, it would execute the query on the database and run the Where on the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to return `IQueryable<T>` with a known model that represents what it is you are returning. You should not return an anonymous type. Also you want to pass in the `DbContext` so it can be disposed of by the caller and not in the method otherwise you will receive an exception that the `DbContext` has been disposed of.

For example:

```
public IQueryable<ProjectModel> GetProjectQuery(ProjectTrackingDBEntities context) {

    return context.TimeEntries.Where(Entry => Entry.Date >= FilterProjectAfterDate
                                && Entry.Date <= FilterProjectBeforerDate
                                && (FilterProjectName != null ? Entry.ProjectName.Contains(FilterProjectName) : true))
        .GroupBy(m => new { m.ProjectName, m.Phase })
        .Join(context.Projects, m => new { m.Key.ProjectName, m.Key.Phase }, w => new { w.ProjectName, w.Phase }, (m, w) => new { te = m, proj = w })
        .Select(m => new ProjectModel
        {
            Name = m.te.Key.ProjectName,
            Phase = m.te.Key.Phase,
            TimeWorked = m.te.Sum(w => w.TimeWorked),
            ProposedCompletionDate = m.proj.ProposedCompletionDate,
            ActualCompletionDate = m.proj.ActualCompletionDate,
            Active = m.proj.Active,
            StartDate = m.proj.StartDate,
            Description = m.proj.Description,
            EstimatedHours = m.proj.EstimatedHours
        });
}
```

**ProjectModel.cs**

```
public class ProjectModel {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Phase {get;set;}
    // rest of properties
}
```

Calling code

```
using (ProjectTrackingDBEntities context = new ProjectTrackingDBEntities())
{   
    var ReturnedQuery = GetProjectsQuery(context);
    foreach(var item in ReturnedQuery)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I see what your saying. Now does it make a difference that I am using an ADO.net model to represent my Projects? Could I avoid having to create a ProjectModel.cs somehow? Or would it just be considered better to go ahead and create the ProjectModel.cs

Comment: @EricObermuller - You can't reuse models that the DbContext type is already aware of (ie. used for mapping). You have to create a new Model that you will project your result into. I guessed on a good name for the model, change it as you see fit. You can also move these to a different namespace if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to return the enumerator, but you can't return an enumerator for an anonymous type, unfortunately. Probably the easiest path forward for you would be to return enumerator over the full row object, like this:

```
public IEnumerable<TimeEntries> GetTimeEntries()
{
    using (ProjectTrackingDBEntities context = new ProjectTrackingDBEntities())
    {
        return context.TimeEntries
            .Where
            (
                Entry => 
                Entry.Date >= FilterProjectAfterDate &&
                Entry.Date <= FilterProjectBeforerDate &&
                (FilterProjectName != null ? Entry.ProjectName.Contains(FilterProjectName) : true)
            )
            .GroupBy(m => new { m.ProjectName, m.Phase })
            .Join
            (
                context.Projects, 
                m => new { m.Key.ProjectName, m.Key.Phase }, 
                w => new { w.ProjectName, w.Phase }, 
                (m, w) => new { te = m, proj = w }
            );
    }
)
```

}

And use it like this:

```
var query = GetTimeEntries();
foreach (var row in query.Select( m => new { Name = row.te.Key.ProjectName })
{
    Console.WriteLine(row.Name);
}
```

Comment: This will throw an `ObjectDisposedException` once the result is enumerated because of the `using` statement on the `DbContext`.

Comment: This is inefficient, because when do the foreach on the query it will issue a database request and return all columns of TimeEntries. The Select will be done on the database results in memory. If you would return an IQueryable instead of an IEnumerable, the select will affect the database query and it will only fetch the ProjectName column.